# i can send cookies in node js but i can not get in next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

i have this code in backEnd nodejs i set token to cookeis and send to front next js but i can not give in frontEnd i set sameSite to none secure to true but i can not give token in cookies i don't have any error

```
const signToken = id => {
  return jwt.sign({ id: id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
  });
};

const createSendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(user._id);

  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ),
    // secure: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
    secure: true,
  };
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true;

  res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);

  // remove the password from the output
  user.password = undefined;

  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'success',
    token,
    data: {
      user: user
    }
  });
};

exports.signup = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  const newUser = await User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm
  });

  createSendToken(newUser, 201, res);
});
```

and send cookie
but in the next js i can not get and resend back cookie

```
  async function onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const json = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/user/login",
        json,
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
      console.log("response", response);
      // if (!response.ok) {
      //   throw new Error("Failed to submit the data. Please try again.");
      // }

      const data = response;
      console.log("data", data);
      // router.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error);
      
      // res.status(error.response.status).json({ message: error.message });
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
     
    }
  }
```

i set cors and set this

```
 sameSite: 'None',
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true
```

i set // httpOnly: true but not working

Comment: no it is localhost and Ok

Comment: no and i have cookie  in the browser but can not send back to node js

Comment: yes but i can not set

Comment: i can not set cookie  in front to send to backEnd When I send and log in for the second time i get in backEnd but i can not send with another request